# Customizing the fields generated by automatic derivation of ToSchema

Tags: haskell, servant, derived-instances

I have the following type:

```
data Device = Device { _deviceId    :: DeviceId
                     , _deviceName  :: Text
                     , _deviceDtype :: DType }
            deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)
makeFields ''Device
$(deriveJSON (mkOptions "_device") ''Device)
```

Here I make use of `deriveJSON` instead of the `Generic` mechanism, since I need to adapt the name of the fields of the JSON representation for this data type:

```
-- | Make JSON conversion options.
mkOptions :: String -> Options
mkOptions prefix = defaultOptions { fieldLabelModifier = removePrefix prefix
                                  , unwrapUnaryRecords = True
                                  }
```

The prefix is needed to generate lenses for the type, but not needed in the JSON representation.

Now I'm trying to generate Swagger documentation, using [servant-swagger](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-swagger-1.1.2.1/docs/Servant-Swagger.html), which requires a [`ToSchema`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/swagger2-2.1.3/docs/Data-Swagger-Internal-Schema.html#t:ToSchema) instance for `Device`. Now the problem is that the generated schema will have the given prefixed names of the accessor functions above (`_deviceId`, `_deviceName`, `_deviceDType`). Instead I would to have the modified version (`id`, `name`, and `dtype`).

Is there a way to customize the generic derivation process in such a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not too familiar with `servant-swagger` and `swagger2` but it looks like something like this should do the job:

```hs
import Data.Swagger.Schema
import Data.Swagger.SchemaOptions

instance ToSchema Device where
  declareNamedSchema =
    genericDeclareNamedSchema
      defaultSchemaOptions {fieldLabelModifier = \fieldLabel -> ...}
```